# Can we include inequalities while solving under determined simultaneous linear equation in reduced Echelon form?

Tags: matrices, inequality, systems-of-equations, integral-inequality

Is there a way to include the inequalities of variables in calculating family of equations while solving under determined simultaneous linear equations?

For Eg: Lets say x + y = 4,  y + z = 4.

But I also have the additional information that x and y are unequal and y and z are unequal. How can I make use of this extra information? Is there a way to include this information in the matrix while calculating reduced Echelon form to family of solutions.

Comment: Introduce further variables that make up the difference e.g. x + y = 4 and x + 2<y is now x + y = 4 with x+2+s = y. You will possibly need conditions on x, y, like they are always positive for example, to get something useful.

Comment: The thing is the only information I have is that they are not equal, I don't know which one is greater, or what exactly is the difference between them. IS there a way to formally include this information in to matrix?

Comment: If you have a set of linear equations then your solutions will form a vector space e.g a point, line or plane if you have 3 variables. You can simply ignore such solutions with equal values.

Comment: @Paul no, the three variable equation was jut for example, I have 18 equations, and  81 variables, now I also have some extra information that some of those variables are not equal to other variables. I can't manually do it, its for a computer program, So is there an algebraic way to solve this?